# What does "degree of freedom" mean in Direction Of Arrival (DOA) estimation?

Tags: signal-processing, antenna-array

Recently, I was reading this paper, [*Nested Arrays: A Novel Approach to Array Processing With Enhanced Degrees of Freedom*](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/5456168). In the abstract, it is mentioned:

> This structure is obtained by systematically nesting two or more uniform linear arrays and can provide \$O(N^2)\$ degrees of freedom using only \$N\$ physical sensors when the second-order statistics of the received data is used.

What does "degree of freedom" mean in this context?

Comment: Since I don't have access to the paper, only the abstract, my best guess is that "degrees of freedom" refers to the number of sources that can be distinguished from the data collected.

Comment: Have you thought about contacting the authors? Professor Vaidyanathan’s contact details are in the Caltech directory, and Associate Professor Pal is on LinkedIn. Before doing that though, you’ve double checked that the meaning is not defined in the body of the paper? It would seem most unlikely that an expression used in the title would not be defined in an academic paper. Hard to tell without access to the body. You’ve read it though right?

Comment: In general it means *any of the directions in which independent action can occur.* Usually, I take this to mean *"orthogonality."* With 2 degrees of freedom, you have two independent variables, so to speak.